# jquery not getting value from select statement on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is really odd, but I am probably missing something simple. I have a simple select statement where a user can choose a value.

onChange calls a function getDrop2() which currently I am trying to get it to alert me which option is chosen.

my html is:

```
<select  onChange= "getDrop2()" id = "drop1" >
     <option value="0">All</option>
     <option value="1">Alphabetical</option>
     <option value="2">Brewery</option>
     <option value="3">Style</option>
</select>
```

My Javascript is:

```
function getDrop2(){
    var choice = $("#drop1").val()
    alert(choice);

}
```

The output of the alert statement is just blank.

Comment: Try using http://api.jquery.com/change/ instead

Comment: @Mike This should work fine. See this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd2H7/). Do you possibly have another element with the same ID?

Comment: @Boaz You were right, I must have had some random thing with a similar name. I changed it to something really random and now it works. Thanks (I thought it should work !)

Comment: @Mike No problem. Now that it's working, consider adopting one of the answers below (Brian's or Adeneo's), as they offer a better and cleaner approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, you're better off doing something like:

```
<select id = "drop1" >
     <option value="0">All</option>
     <option value="1">Alphabetical</option>
     <option value="2">Brewery</option>
     <option value="3">Style</option>
</select>
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
 $(function(){
    $('#drop1').change(function() {
        var choice = $(this).val();
        alert(choice);
    }
  });
```

The idea is that jQuery is now attaching the change function automatically to the select with the id of "drop1"  By using this pattern, you've decoupled the HTML from the JavaScript that's doing the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Although what others have selected is a better approach. My answer is just to tell you why your code is not working

Try this

```
var choice = $('#drop1 option:selected').val()
```

Instead of

```
var choice = $("#drop1").val()
```