# .change not working as expected

Tags: jquery, onchange

I am trying to learn how to use the change function in jquery but I cannot seem to trigger a function. Since I'm not the best at this, I figured i'd try someone else's code but that isn't working either. I copied the code from the first answer on this question

[jquery not getting value from select statement on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822476/jquery-not-getting-value-from-select-statement-on-change)

Html

```
<select id="drop1">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">Alphabetical</option>
<option value="2">Brewery</option>
<option value="3">Style</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
 $(function () {
 $('#drop1').change(function () {
     var choice = $(this).val();
     alert(choice);
 }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jCLJ9/

but I still can't get it to work. Here is the link i'm using for Jquery 
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: You are missing `)` see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jCLJ9/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below thing buddy u missed closing bracket

```
$(function () {
    $('#drop1').change(function () {
        var choice = $(this).val();
        alert(choice);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have typos

```
$(function () {
    $('#drop1').change(function () {
        var choice = $(this).val();
        alert(choice);
    });
});
```

---

Change in your code

```
$(function () {
 $('#drop1').change(function () {
     var choice = $(this).val();
     alert(choice);
 } //remover this extra } 
 });
// add extra }); for closing DOM Ready function
```

---

Instead of `$(this).val();` you can use `this.value`

Answer (score 2):

should be like this

```
 $('#drop1').change(function(e) {
    var choice = $(this).val();
    alert(choice);
});
```

you forget to enclose the .change() event properly.

here is your working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/jCLJ9/2/

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the function call to `change` so you're likely getting syntax errors in your JavaScript console.  Note your version:

```
$('#drop1').change(function () {
  var choice = $(this).val();
  alert(choice);
}
```

The closing `}` ends the anonymous `function`, but the parentheses for the `change()` call are still open.  You need to close them:

```
$('#drop1').change(function () {
  var choice = $(this).val();
  alert(choice);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing closing braces causing the error:

```
 $(function(){
    $('#drop1').change(function() {
        var choice = $(this).val();
        alert(choice);
    });
  });
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jCLJ9/3/)